# Pandas: groupby двух столбцов и уточнение значения в третьем

Tags: python, pandas

Такое работает

```
df.groupby('column_1').target.mean()
```

такое тоже ok

```
df.groupby(["column_1", "column_2"])["target"].transform("mean")
```

и такое

```
df.groupby(df['column_1'][df['target'] == 1]).size()
```

такое (groupby по двум колонкам + уточнение данных по третьей) нет:

```
df.groupby(df['column_1','column_2'][df['target'] == 1]).size()
```

Какие именно функции типа size или mean на конце - не важно.

Ошибка:

```
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

....if tolerance is not None ... KeyError: ('column_1', 'column_2')
```

что делать?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Вы можете попробовать заменить `df['column_1','column_2']` -> `df[['column_1','column_2']]`, но по-моему у вас логическая ошибка в коде с группировкой. Лучше объяснить что вы пытаетесь сделать на примере данных, тогда можно будет посоветовать что-то более предметно

Comment: А там не просто `groupby(['column_1','column_2'])` должно быть? У вас реально что-то странное